# how to set default option of node reference cck field through form alter

Tags: drupal, hook-form-alter, form-alter

I accept the arg from the url and according to the arg value I need to set the default option value, here is the code:

```
function ims_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {


switch ($form_id) {

  case 'media_content_node_form':

    unset($form['buttons']['preview']);

    $form['#redirect'] = 'mediacontent';

    if(is_numeric(arg(3)))
    {
      $arg_nid = arg(3);
      foreach($form['field_media_model']['#options'] as $k=>$v)
              {
        if($v==$arg_nid)
        {
        $form['field_media_model']['#default_value'] = $v;
        } 

      }
    }

    break;
  }

}
```

Comment: What type of widget is field_media_model using?

Comment: thanks for your attention: it's select box - node reference. I got the answer, i was accessing the values wrongly, now i am using $form['field_media_model']['#default_value'][0]['nid'] to set default value;

Comment: Stop suggesting invalid edits to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656378/how-to-display-mysql-record-using-a-combobox-in-php-ajax) - they are rejected because you removed the image. If you don't know how to edit properly, don't do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should steer away from a `switch` construction if you are only testing one thing; use an `if`.

Second, as per your own comment, you were using the variables wrong.

And third, why all the extra cruft, such as unsetting values, looping trough #options, and redirecting?

```
function ims_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'media_content_node_form') {
    $nid = arg(3);

    if(($nid = arg(3)) && is_int($nid)) {
      $form['field_media_model']['#default_value'][0]['nid'] = $nid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the question is simplified to understand the scenario, their are multiple cases and all other stuff is according to my custom needs,i have done with this problem it's resolved now **(mentioned as comment section of question itself.)**

Comment: For me it worked when i used: $form['field_media_model'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'][] = $nid;

Answer (score 0):

i was accessing the value of element wrongly, because it's a node reference field the right way to access that element is `$form['field_media_model']['#default_value'][0]['nid']`

Comment: Which is what I answered too :)